# c# Individual User Accounts - Multiple Competitions

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm writing a program at the moment that is a competition platform. I intent on allowing multiple competitions to be run at once and separate them through subdomains. What I would like to do is have the IdentityUser tied to the individual subdomain of a competition. I'm kind of half way there but need a nudge in how to best approach this. Here is the DB at the moment:

Competiton Table

- ID (primary key)
- Name

AspNetUsers

- (Usual columns)
- CompID (Foreign key from Competiton Table)

What I would like to do is update the Login.aspx page to check whether the user that's signing in with the subdomain for example comp1.compeititons.com is registered to that. I've got the register page already assigning the foreign key so I've got the data there. Also, if I can make this work will a user with the same username be able to register to multiple competitions or will IdentityManager throw and error because it's found the user in the database already?

Comment: Perhaps update with the actual c#/blazor code you tried, describe your one issue with that and we can help you fix your one issue with that?

Comment: Hi Mark, I haven't actually tried anything yet as I think I'm getting myself rather confused with how best to go about it. This is the Login check that I'm using at the moment:

var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Username, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

Basically id like to modify that await function to also include competition ID which I can retrieve using a simple lookup to the DB just before by captuing the subdomain but I'm unsure if that's even possible.